# Efficiently perform updates on every kth element in an array

Tags: c++, optimization, data-structures

I have a zero-initialized boolean array of size **N**, and a set of distinct positive integers **S**.

For each element in **S** denoted as **e**, I would like to set every element whose 1-indexed number is divisible by **e** to true.

For example, given **N**=6 and **S**={2, 3}, the resulting array would be {0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1}.

A simple implementation of this in C++ would look like this:

```
bool arr[N]{};
for(int e : S) {
    for(int i = e-1; i < N; i += e) {
        arr[i] = true;
    }
}
```

This works just fine, however, it is not fast enough. Given that **S** could have up to **N** elements, this results in a quadratic time complexity O(**N**^2).

Note that I only need to calculate the number of elements in the array that are set to true in the end.

So I was wondering, is there a faster way to approach this since I only need to know the number of true values in the array afterwards?

Preferably in a time complexity of O(**N**log**N**) or better.

Comment: Counting boolean set might be done mathematically, `6/2+6/3-6/(2*3)`.

Comment: I think the general case here works out to be the [Sieve of Eratosthenes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes#:~:text=trial%20division%20sieve.-,Algorithmic%20complexity,asymptotically%20approaches%20log%20log%20n.), which is O(n log log n).

Comment: The array is periodic, for the example given it repeats every six (two times three) elements, so that's one way to reduce the complexity, too.

Comment: Investigate "timing wheels".  This is the idea of keeping a priority heap of "next times" which holds (only) the "next" multiples of all the elements of **S** that you haven't reached yet.  (Obviously you don't even need the array **N** to exist at all.)   Complexity is the _O(n log n)_ you seek, based on the computational complexity of a priority heap. [DuckDuckGo](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=timing+wheel+for+event+tasks&atb=v311-1&ia=web)

Comment: Actually @Jarod42 's comment shows the right way to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, your complexity is in no way O(N<sup>2</sup>), since the cardinality of **S** is not strictly linked to that of **N**, we can say that your program runs in O(N*k) where k = |**S**|.

For k << **N**, there **might** be a solution that is faster...

### The theory

that is, given a set of numbers:

[image]

We can construct a sequence of their multiples **M**, and we are also assured that **M** is going to repeat exactly after [image] times, that is, after we compute this sequence up to the number obtained by multiplying all members of **s**, we can tile it infinitely, we are going to call this special number **L**.

This, in turn, means that if we have a producer of such a sequence (which still requires to perform the above algorithm for the first **L** numbers), we can then use the resulting sequence to randomly access our array and set the bits to true, thus amortizing the costs

### A possible implementation

First off, we can define a function to generate this sequence **M**, then another to properly fill the array given this sequence, we call both and then print the result to `stdout`:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <ranges>
#include <numeric>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <concepts>

#define N 6


[[nodiscard]] constexpr std::vector<int> MultiplesSequence(std::ranges::range auto const& range, int max_size) noexcept {  
        
        int max = std::accumulate(range.begin(), range.end(), 1, std::multiplies<int>());
        // avoid calculating multiples if the don't correspond to indices in the array
        max = std::min(max, max_size);

        std::vector<int> multiples;
        for(auto n : std::ranges::views::iota(1, max)) {
            if(std::ranges::any_of(range, [n](auto&& i) { return n % i == 0; })) {
                multiples.push_back(n);
            }
        }

        return multiples;
    }

constexpr void fill_bool(auto& bool_arr, auto const& multiples)
{
    // we might have optimized all multiples out
    if(multiples.empty()) {
        return;
    }
    // not the most elegant solution for wraparound
    auto highest = multiples.back();
    auto times = 1 + N  / highest;

    for(int n = 1; n <= times; ++n) {
        for(auto m : multiples) {
            if(n * m <= N)
            {
                bool_arr[n * m - 1] = true;
            }
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    bool arr[N]{};
    std::vector<int> S = {2, 3};
    auto multiples = MultiplesSequence(S, N);
    fill_bool(arr, multiples);

    std::copy(arr, arr + N, std::ostream_iterator<bool>(std::cout, " "));

}
```

In general, a person more proficient with the language might come up with an implementation based on `std::unreachable_sentinel` to properly simulate an infinite sequence and then take from it from a view adaptor, in a similar way as what is shown [in this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70777344/), this gets the job done anyway.

This way, we pay an O(L*k) cost (we find the multiples only up to the special length **L**) and then we can quickly insert the rest in linear time, how much this is worth in practice warrants profiling.

Comment: Your PNG images are using black text on a transparent background.  Browsers running in Dark Mode can't view the text very well when the browser's background is dark. Consider changing the images to use a solid white background instead.

Comment: [LCM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Least_common_multiple) might be used instead of full product.

Answer (score 1):

A simple optimization improves things quite a bit if members of **S** can be multiples of other members of **S**

```
bool arr[N]{};
for(int e : S) {
    if (arr[e-1] != true) {
        for(int i = e-1; i < N; i += e) {
            arr[i] = true;
        }
    }
}
```

The idea being that if `arr[e-1]` has already been set, then all of its multiples have been, as well.

Comment: This will be more effective if you sort S first.